# Programatically Pre-selecting Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to have a drop down option pre-selected based on a string that I have on the server side.  For example I have the following options:

```
<select name="postsport">
    <option value="choose">Choose a sport</option>
    <option value="general sea">--general sea--</option>
    <option value="sailing">sailing</option>
    <option value="diving">diving</option>
    <option value="sailing">surfing</option>
    <option value="kiteboarding">kite boarding</option>
    <option value="kayaking">kayaking</option>
    <option value="general land">--general land--</option>
    <option value="rockclimbing">rock climbing</option>
    <option value="hiking">hiking</option>
</select>
```

And on the serverside I know that the pre-chosen option is "sailing" is there any way with javascript or jquery or some other method to have this option prechosen and out on the front?

Comment: Why not selecting the option on the serverside?

Comment: which server-side language you are using?

Comment: I am choosing it in the server side. I just want to know how to display the chosen option. Polin I am using python and jinja2 as my temp lathing engine

Answer (score 2):

If you want do it via js:

```
$('option[value=sailing]').attr('selected','selected')
```

Comment: is that just straight js? what else do I need to add? to the option section

Comment: Nothing, though there's many ways to do what you want to do as many people commented. That script searches for an `<option>` tag with `value="sailing"` and adds an attribute `selected="selected"` to it.

Answer (score 1):

When you generate the HTML just modified the default option to say

```
<option value="sailing" selected="selected">sailing</option>
```

Leave everything else as is.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php  if($selected){ 
 echo "<option value=\"choose\" selected=\"selected\">Choose a sport</option>";}
?>
```